# Is CNC milling on metals always followed by heat treatment?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

CNC milling causes residual stresses in metals.
So, after CNC milling of a metal part, say aluminium, do all manufacturers (I'm not referring to any specific manufacturer, just generally) heat treat such parts parts after milling?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I wanted to know whether aluminium parts are heat treated after CNC milling to a desired shape to relieve the part of residual stresses caused by milling.

Comment: It is unusual to heat-treat any metal to remove machining stresses .  It is common to heat-treat metals after machining for reasons other than removing machining stress.

Comment: it is common to pre-anneal metal pieces before machining to release stresses locked into the microstructure during the initial forming processes. these stresses can be more significant than machining stresses.

Comment: The answer to your headline question is "No." What gave you the impression that it might "always" be the case?

Answer (score 4):

No. CNC machining is done in a huge variety of industries and applications, many of which do not benefit from heat treatment.

CNC machining - and metal cutting in general - is an incredibly broad technology. It is used frequently in demanding industries and applications, and many of these (aerospace, performance sports, power generation) do benefit from heat treatment post-processes. But CNC machining is also used in low value and low volume applications, and heat treatment is often overkill or even destructive there. For instance, CNC machining is used to create sacrificial parts (like soft jaws) which are used once and then discarded; it would be a waste of time and resources to heat treat these, and doing so might result in damage to the final part (which is meant to be held gently in a *soft* material).

Even if you narrowed your question to a specific industry or application, the reality is that heat treating (or any other technology, for that matter) is only applied to a subset of the parts in that field.

Answer (score 1):

Heat treatments can be applied to many metal composites to radically improve key physical properties (for instance hardness, quality or machinability). These progressions occur because of alterations to the microstructure and, some of the time, the substance creation of the material.

Heat treatments can be applied to metal compounds all through the assembling cycle. For CNC machined parts, heat medicines are regularly applied either:

Before CNC machining: When a normalized evaluation of a metal compound is mentioned that is promptly accessible, the CNC specialist co-op will machine the parts straightforwardly from that stock material. This is regularly the most ideal choice for decreasing lead times.

After CNC machining: Some Heat treatments altogether increment the hardness of the material or are utilized as a completing advance in the wake of shaping. In these cases, the Heat treatments are applied after CNC machining, as high hardness diminishes the machinability of a material. For instance, this is standard practice when CNC machining device steel parts.

Comment: I dont see an answer to the actual question here. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

not really. CNC reduces volume/mass of a pre-selected already fabricated material (Steel, aluminum, titanium) there's No need to heat treat it, as it was already done when made as a block. If heat deformation/degredation was anticipated, cooling systems are part of professional grade CNC.

[image]